# Regex for ONLY positive and negative integer in input formatter for a TextFormField

Tags: regex, flutter

I am trying to have a `TextFormField` which only accepts negative and positive number of 5 digits.

The following code but it does restrict digits only and up to 5, but it is not accepting a negative sign.

```
new TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    enableSuggestions: false,
    inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(5),
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'-?[0-9]')),
    ],
    onChanged: (val) {},
);
```

I have tried the following regex: "-?[0-9]" but it does not allow the negative sign.

Comment: Try `RegExp(r'-?\d*$')` instead? Does that suit your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by @Randal-Schwartz formatters evaluate every new input which results in that every intermediate string shall match the filter, including when starting to type a negative number, and the minus sign "-" alone does not match the regex.

In addition, as per the docs of `FilteringTextInputFormatter`, this formatter **should not be used for patterns are meant for matching the whole string** (for examples with [RegExp]s that contain positional matchers (`^` or `$`)).

## Solution

Using a `TextInputFormatter` with a function which checks if the input can be parsed into an Int and returns the previous input otherwise.

```dart
new TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    enableSuggestions: false,
    inputFormatters: [
        TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldV, newV) => onlyIntegersFormatter(oldV, newV, precision: 5)),
    ],
    onChanged: (val) {},
);
```

```dart
static TextEditingValue onlyIntegersFormatter(final TextEditingValue oldValue, final TextEditingValue newValue, {final int? precision}) {
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty || newValue.text == '-') {
      return newValue;
    } else {
      // Check if the input can be parsed into an Int and returns the previous input otherwise.
      final int? newVal = int.tryParse(newValue.text);

      if (newVal == null) {
        return oldValue;
      } else {
        // Check for number of digits.
        if (digits != null) {
          return  math.pow(10, precision) > newVal.abs() ? newValue : oldValue;
        }
        return newValue;
      }
    }
};
```

### Alternative Solution

If Regex is still the go to solution:

```dart
new TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    enableSuggestions: false,
    inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^-?\d{0,5}')),
    ],
    onChanged: (val) {},
);
```

Explanation of the regex:

- ^: Matches the start of the input string.
- -?: Matches the "-" sign zero or one times.
- \d{1,5}: Matches zero to five digits. The \d shorthand character class matches any digit.

Answer (score 4):

Change`RegExp(r'-?[0-9]')` to `RegExp(r'^-?[0-9]*')`. It's not letting you input a "-" because your expression is saying that you must have a number, but just solely "-" invalidates that so the formatter doesn't let you input the negative.

Comment: It should be '^-?[0-9]*' to force the sign at the start of the input string, otherwise the `FilteringTextInputFormatter` also matches repeating and intermediate minus "-" such as "--651" or "65-23"

Comment: You right, made the change

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using an input filter is that every intermediate string must also match the filter.  Since your filter cannot match a minus sign "on the way to" typing "-3", it doesn't work.

This is when you must abandon using input filters, and instead put your validation into the validator, which will be applied only when checked, and won't prevent intermediate combinations from being typed enroute.

Comment: Indeed that is the reason why using a regex is not be advised in the case of matching the whole input, however leaving the logic to the `validator` may result in a bad UX. Better use `TextInputFormatter.withFunction`.

Comment: I don't see how that helps.  If the function still doesn't permit a naked "-", then you still won't be able to type "-3".  The only solution is to have a non-blocking way to show "failed" on - but then update to "ok" on "-3", and that's best done with the validator.

Comment: I agree. In the proposed solution I have included that check `newValue.text == '-'` to be able to type "-". Indeed a validator could be used to verify that on "-" is "failed" and "-3" is OK, but it could also be implemented with `onChanged: (val) => this.value = int.tryParse(val) ?? 0`